# Labelling a point in the coordinate system with a dashed line corresponding to the x-axis and y-axis

Tags: plotting

In the image made with the following code, I want to start from points {4, -1} and make two dashed lines perpendicular to the x-axis and y-axis, respectively.

```
Plot[{Sin[π  x], Log[1/4, x], -1}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 8, 1}], Table[t, {t, -5, 5, 0.5}]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabels -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline", 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[3], Red, Point[{{4, -1}, {4, 0}}], 
   Dashed, Line[{{4, 0}, {4, -1}}], Line[{{0, -1}, {4, -1}}]}]
```

The above code returns the following result.
[image]

Is there any other better method?

The target outcome is as follows:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? This seems perfectly fine what you've done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using `Projection`:**

```
pt = {4, -1};

Plot[{Sin[π x], Log[1/4, x], -1}
 , {x, 0, 5}
 , Ticks -> {Range[0, 8], Range[-5, 5, 0.5]}
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 , PlotLabels -> Automatic
 , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesLabel -> {x, y}
 , AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}]
 , ImageSize -> Medium
 , Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[3], Red
   , Point[{{4, -1}, {4, 0}}]
   , Dashed
   , Line[{pt, Projection[pt, {1, 0}]}]
   , Line[{pt, Projection[pt, {0, 1}]}]
   , Black, Text[pt, pt, {0, 2}]
   }
 ]
```

---

[image]

Comment: I use v12.2.0 and since `PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline"` is a more recent addition, this provides a convenient workaround.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Show[
 Plot[{Sin[π    x], Log[1/4, x]}, {x, 0, 5},
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 8], Range[-5, 5, 0.5]},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotLabels -> Automatic,
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline",
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point[{4, 0}]}],
 Plot[-1, {x, 0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][3],
  PlotHighlighting ->
   Placed[{"Dropline", <|"Style" -> {Red, Dashed}|>}, 4]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The coordinates of the points obtained using Dropline are not accurate

Comment: Add `Exclusions -> {4}` to the second plot. Since the function is constant, the sampling is very low. Adding the exclusion will cause sampling in that vicinity.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just continue your line?

```
Line[{{4, 0}, {4, -1}, {0, -1}}]
```

Comment: Is there any other good way?

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[{Sin[\[Pi] x], Log[1/4, x], -1}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 8], Range[-5, 5, 0.5]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Medium,

 GridLines -> {{4}, {-1}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashing[0.05], Thickness[0.01], Red],
 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], Red, Point[{{4, -1}, {4, 0}}],
   
   Text[Style["{4,-1}", 18, Black, 
     Background -> Yellow], {3.5, -1.2}]}]
```

[image]